# How to extract all anchor tags using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I would like to be able to extract all the anchor tags from my input string,  under the heading `picks`.

**For example, here is my input feed going into bottom variable:**

```
string bottom = "<P align=justify><STRONG>picks<BR>
<A href="/Article.aspx? article=froth&amp;PUB=250&amp;ISS=22787&amp;SID=51610" name=""  target=_blank>froth</A></STRONG>: Text...<BR><STRONG>
<A href="/Article.aspx?article=Bouncing back&amp;PUB=250&amp;ISS=22787&amp;SID=51603" name="" target=_blank>Bouncing back</A></STRONG>: Text...<BR><STRONG></P>"
```

C# function :

```
     string bottom = reader.GetString(1);

                string price = "";
                if (bottom.ToLower().Contains("picks"))
                {

                    price = bottom.Substring(bottom.IndexOf("picks"), 5);

                    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();

                    html.LoadHtml(bottom);
                    var anchors = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("A");

                        foreach (var a in anchors)
                        {
                            result = a.OuterHtml;
                        }

                }
```

My issue is, the above function is only able to extract the last anchor as an output, from the input string, whereas the input string contains two anchor tags.  I tried using `Any()` method with the anchor variable, but I could not get the desired result with that also.

any further help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I got both anchors by running your code (with very small changes)

Comment: your code works for me as it is

Comment: yup your code works for me too...